# Creating a object from Datarow

Tags: design-patterns, c#-4.0, datatable

i want to create a object from a DataRow object.it can be done by traversing the Datarow object. but here  the  constraint is DataRow columns are not fixed. there can be variation in no of columns a DataRow can have. i can't traverse DataRow according to ColumnName as i dont know which all columns will be in datarow.

for example i have a class

```
class Abc
{
    string attrib1;
    string attrib2;
    string attrib2;

    public Abc(DataRow dr)
    {
        attrib1 = dr["attrib1"].ToString();
        attrib2 = dr["attrib2"].ToString();
        attrib3 = dr["attrib3"].ToString();
    }
}
```

this will work fine when DataRow object has all three columns.
but if not then this will throw exception

Please help me.

i have tried using switch case in constructor as follows

```
class Abc
{
    string attrib1;
    string attrib2;
    string attrib2;

    public Abc(DataRow dr)
    {
         foreach (System.Data.DataColumn dc in record.Columns)
             {
                  switch (dc.ColumnName)
                  { 
                case "attrib1" :
                    attrib1 = dr["attrib1"].ToString();
                    break;
                case "attrib2" :
                    attrib2 = dr["attrib2"].ToString();
                    break;
                case "attrib2" :
                    attrib3 = dr["attrib3"].ToString();
                    break;
            } 
                  }  
           } 
     }
```

though it is working fine, i want to know whether this approach is fine.

please help to solve this problem

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is not good.

1- Please make your "attrib1", "attrib2", "attrib3" as constants.

2- Please see the pseudocode:

```
if (dr[CONSTANT_ATT1] != null) then attrib1 = dr[CONSTANT_ATT1].ToString();
if (dr[CONSTANT_ATT2] != null) then attrib2 = dr[CONSTANT_ATT2].ToString();
if (dr[CONSTANT_ATT3] != null) then attrib3 = dr[CONSTANT_ATT3].ToString();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it is really better that using switch cases

Answer (score 0):

I think the switch case is ok, however, it's a good idea to add a `default` label and throw an exception there. This will save you a lot of debugging when you add a new column to your query.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the values, you can simply get the DataRow as an object array with this line of code

```
object[] itemArray = dr.ItemArray;
```